# Loop append of numpy array element in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, append

Who can explain how to loop add an element to the numpy array by condition?

I wrote some code that should do add element `2` if i element of array `A` is `0` and add element `1` if i element of array `A` is not `0`.

Here is the code itself:

```
import numpy as np
def finalconcat(somearray):
  for i in somearray:
    arraysome=[]
    if somearray[i]==0:
      arraysome=np.append(arraysome,[2],axis=0)
    else:
      arraysome=np.append(arraysome,[1],axis=0)
  return arraysome
```

Let me give you an example:

```
A=np.array([1,0,2,3,4,5])
C=finalconcat(B)
print(C)
```

It should come out:

```
[1,2,1,1,1,1]
```

But it comes out like:

```
[1.]
```

Please explain to me what is wrong here, I just don't understand what could be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. `arraysome=[]` is inside your loop so for each iteration of `somearray` you are emptying `arraysome`. Consequently, you can never end up with more than one element in `arraysome` when you are all done.
2. You have `for i in somearray`. On each iteration `i` will be the next element of `somearray`; it will *not* be iterating *indices* of the array. Yet later you have `if somearray[i]==0:`. This should just be `if i==0:`.
3. If you want the resulting elements of `arraysome` to be integers rather than floats, then you should initialize it to be a an `numpy` array of integers.
4. You have `C=finalconcat(B)`, but `B` is not defined.
5. You should really spend some time reading the [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

```py
import numpy as np

def finalconcat(somearray):
    arraysome = np.array([], dtype=np.int)
    for i in somearray:
        if i == 0:
            arraysome = np.append(arraysome, [2], axis=0)
        else:
            arraysome = np.append(arraysome, [1], axis=0)
    return arraysome

a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
c = finalconcat(a)
print(c)
```

Prints:

```None
[1 2 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: I have updated the code and explanation because I found an additional problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

For  iteration like this it's better to use lists.  `np.append` is just a poorly named cover for `np.concatenate`, which returns a whole new array with each call.  List append works in-place, and is more efficient.  And easier to use:

```
def finalconcat(somearray):
  rec = [2 if i==0 else 1 for i in somearray]
  # arr = np.array(rec)
  return rec

In [31]: a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [32]: np.array([2 if i==0 else 1 for i in a])
Out[32]: array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

But it's better to use whole-array methods, such as:

```
In [33]: b = np.ones_like(a)
In [34]: b
Out[34]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [35]: b[a==0] = 2
In [36]: b
Out[36]: array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

or

```
In [37]: np.where(a==0, 2, 1)
Out[37]: array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```